# Dask distributed worker task allocation

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Dask distribute when the tasks are submitted by default. If we have a task run time depends on input and some input may cause the task run much longer than other, we may end up with all long running tasks assigned to one worker. Here is an example to illustrate the issue:

```
import time

from distributed import Client, wait


def uneven_task(num):
    """If num is odd number, it will take much longer to complete"""
    print(f"Running task {num}")
    if num % 2 != 0:
        time.sleep(num*100)
    print(f"Task {num} has finished. Worker is free.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client(address="xx.xxx.xx.xx:8786")
    futures = []
    for i in range(10):
        future = client.submit(uneven_task, i, priority=1)
        futures.append(future)

    wait(futures)
```

2 workers started. 10 tasks submitted. Odd number input will lead to a long task, but even number task will be quick. I can see all 5 short tasks allocate to one worker and the other 5 long running tasks all allocate to the other workers.
[image: dashboard]

Is there any way we can config dask only assign task when worker is free instead of allocate them at the time when tasks are submitted?